# ReactJs adding Third party Javascript Plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a Javascript plugin TypeIt to a reactjs(version 17.2). Even though it has npm i am trying to use the plain vanilla js version.
I can't figure this out.

I have used the following hook to inject script to the body

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const useScript = resourceUrl=> {
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = resourceUrl;
    script.async = true;
    console.log(script)
    document.body.appendChild(script);
return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [resourceUrl]);
};
export default useScript;
```

In the component I am using the following code

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import useScript from '../../Hooks/useScript'

const TypeText = () => {

    useScript('vendor/typeTextScript.js')
    // useScript('https://unpkg.com/typeit@8.0.6/dist/index.umd.js')
    const typeTrigger = useRef()
    
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        
            setTimeout(() => {
                new TypeIt(typeTrigger.current, {
                    strings: "This is my string!",
                    speed: 75,
                    loop: true,
                  }).go();
            }, 100);
          
    },[])
    

    return (
        <>
            <h1>This is a TypeText component</h1>
            <p ref={typeTrigger}></p>



        </>
    )
}

export default TypeText
```

I am getting the following error:  TypeIt is not defined.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use `npm` to install that package but here is what you need to do:

add `type` property to your `script` so browser would know how to deal with it

```
const useScript = (resourceUrl: string) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = resourceUrl;
    script.async = true;
    script.type = "text/javascript"; // you need to add this line
    console.log(script);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [resourceUrl]);
};
```

Comment: Added `script.type`. Still the error persists. Eventhough the Library file is loaded, the initialisation is not getting triggered.

I am not using NPM coz, a situation may arise where we need to use a particular JS plugin, but no NPM for the same.

Comment: I have found out if we remove  the following configuration `"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },` from package.json file, the above code works. ESLint configuration is causing the issue. I don't know why

Comment: Found out the issue. Since eslint is already configured, we need to comment the initialisation section like
`setTimeout(() => {
                /*global TypeIt*/
                new TypeIt(typeTrigger.current, {strings: "This is my string!",speed: 75,loop: true, }).go();}, 100);`
We need to comment it as **/*global someFunction, a*/**

Comment: @RejinJose That's Nice, if the answer was helpful, try upvoting and accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Ya sure. will do